# How to use requests.get to access a URL with text formatted as a JSON, save as a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I am trying to use requests to access a URL with text formatted as a JSON. In the following code, everything works, but I want it to be a dictionary, however the type of the response I requested is: 'class method' (I had printed the type of the wrong object the first time). How can I make the information a dictionary?

```
import requests
import json 
r=requests.get('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches1.json')
match_histories = r.json()
print(type(match_histories))
```

The code never gets past the line

```
match_histories = r.json()
```

It just says its running (It doesn't freeze up).

However, if I download the file and try it, it works (I want it to download from the website directly though)

```
with open('matches1', 'r') as json_file:
    match_histories = json.load(json_file)
match_histories['matches']
```

produces what I was hoping for.

I read about using requests on JSONs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Note the file is very large, and is in the appropriate format for a dictionary.

The file I want to load can be [downloaded](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches1.json) but the structure is basically:

```js
{
    "matches": [
        {
            "matchId": 1778839570,
            "region": "NA",
            "platformId": "NA1",
            "matchMode": "CLASSIC",
            "matchType": "MATCHED_GAME",
            "matchCreation": 1427867835805,
            "matchDuration": 3424,
            "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
            "mapId": 11,
            "season": "SEASON2015",
            "matchVersion": "5.6.0.194",
            "participants": [
                // more dictionaries
                ],
            "participantIdentities": [
                // more dictionaries
            ],
            "teams": [
                // more dictionaries
            ],
            "timeline": {
                "frames": [
                    // many frame dictionaries
                ],
                "frameInterval": 60000
            }
        },

        // more dictionaries
    ]
}
```

The answer is probably quite simple. I apologize, I am new to Python/programming.

How do I save the information from the URL as a dictionary?

It works, took forever. Why does the step

```
match_histories=r.json()
```

take so much longer than

```
match_histories =json.load(json_file)
```

?

Comment: `r.json()`, it's a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the method `.json()` of the response object:

```
r = requests.get('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches1.json')
match_histories = r.json()
```

Comment: This is what I did, but when I type 
match_histores['matches'], I get a Type error

Comment: @Mark you must have a typo somewhere then

Comment: Ineed, I did... I wrote r.json without the (). However, when I run match_histories = r.json() , the code seems to have issues, not proceeding further. I will wait and see if it is just taking a long time, but it has been 5-10 minutes of running the code, with no progress beyond that line

Comment: It just took forever.